# PHP into database with dynamic form with javascript (codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to insert multiple data (PHP CodeIgniter) using array. but I still find an error. The error is array is not clear

```
function insert(){

    $hitung=count($_POST['pembicara']);

    $pengisi=implode(',',$_POST['pembicara']);
    $materi=implode(',',$_POST['materi']);
    $alasan=implode(',',$_POST['alasan']);

    $datapembicara = array(
    'id_kegiatan'   => $x,
    'nama_pembicara'   => $pengisi,                                         
    'materi'      => $materi,                                           
    'alasan'      => $alasan,
    );

    $this->m_admin_smf->add_pembicara($datapembicara);
}
```

when I var_dump show the result like

```
array (size=4)
  'id_kegiatan' => int 990550
  'nama_pembicara' => string '1,2' (length=9)
  'materi' => string '1,2' (length=3)
  'alasan' => string '1,2' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  'id_kegiatan' => int 990550
  'nama_pembicara' => string '1,2' (length=9)
  'materi' => string '1,2' (length=3)
  'alasan' => string '1,2' (length=3)
```

the result is should be like

```
array (size=4)
  'id_kegiatan' => int 990550
  'nama_pembicara' => string '1' (length=9)
  'materi' => string '1' (length=3)
  'alasan' => string '1' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  'id_kegiatan' => int 990550
  'nama_pembicara' => string '2' (length=9)
  'materi' => string '2' (length=3)
  'alasan' => string '2' (length=3)
```

what should I do?

How if like this? but show an error

```
$hitung = count($_POST['pembicara']);
$datapembicara = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $hitung; $i++) {
    $datapembicara[] = array(
        'id_kegiatan' => $x,
        'nama_pembicara' => $_POST['pembicara'][$i],
        'materi' => $_POST['materi'][$i],
        'alasan' => $_POST['alasan'][$i],
    );
}

$this->m_admin_smf->add_pembicara($datapembicara);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them on a series of batches, then you'll have to do something other than `implode` since the behavior will be different from the one you need. You can use a simple `for` loop to create such array structure into series of batches:

```
// Controller
function insert()
{

    $hitung = count($_POST['pembicara']);
    $datapembicara = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $hitung; $i++) {
        $datapembicara[] = array(
            'id_kegiatan' => $x,
            'nama_pembicara' => $_POST['pembicara'][$i],
            'materi' => $_POST['materi'][$i],
            'alasan' => $_POST['alasan'][$i],
        );
    }

    var_dump($datapembicara);

    $this->m_admin_smf->add_pembicara($datapembicara);
}
```

Sidenote: I'd suggest use `input` class of codeigniter since it can handle XSS for you.

```
$value = $this->input->post('value', true); // add true parameter flag
```

Then after said array is made, you can use `->insert_batch()` of active record. It'll do the multiple insertions for you, plus, your values are automatically escaped.

```
// Model
public function add_pembicara($data)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch($data);
}
```

Comment: Okay Its work,but If I want to insert into database , its show an error like ----INSERT INTO `kegiatan_pembicara` (`0`, `1`, `2`) VALUES (Array, Array, Array)----

Comment: @Fatchul i revised some parts of my answer, so that you'd be able to use your newly created array, into `insert_batch()` inside your model

Comment: @Fatchul by the way, could you also post your view files, post the form also, along with `var_dump($_POST)`